# exceptions for rewrite rule in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

How do I make it so that:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ spotsite.php?pid=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Doesn't match my homepage, which is `www.mysite.com`? As of now, every time I navigate to my main page, it annoyingly redirects me to this spotsite as well.. I don't want this to happen.. I only want to redirect only if it's `www.mysite.com/somerandomnumberhere`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this rule prior to the one mentioned:

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ index.html [L]
```

Change index.html with whatever your directory index page is (index.php, etc). You can also replace index.html with just `/` if you wish to preserve the url.

Comment: if I do that then the second rewrite rule (the one I had above) doesn't work, it always goes to the homepage

Comment: now it always redirects me to the spotsite.php?pid no matter what. So mysite.com will be redirected to the spotsite.php?pid, while it should go to index.php